# Health-check daemon doesn't send Host header

Tags: nginx, django

I have a django application running behind nginx.

All of it is running behind a load balancer.
Load balancer is using HTTP health-check to enable/disable nodes.

The problem is that health-check doesn't send a host header and django fails to proceed a request.

I tried to overwrite HOST in nginx but no luck.

```
location /health-check {
    access_log off;
    uwsgi_pass  application;
    proxy_read_timeout  10;
    proxy_pass_header Server;

    proxy_set_header Host health-check.xxxxx.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host health-check.xxxxx.com;

    include     /opt/conf/uwsgi_params;
}
```

Any way to manage it?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54445441/307511